How can i remove fractions from the first string in this list of lists?
e.g i have the following:
test = [['6 / 24 hello','4 / 5 askdskjf'],['2 / 3 dentist']]

i'd like to remove 6 / 24 and 2 /3 so the first string which contains a fraction. to get:
[[' hello', '4 / 5 askdskjf'], [' dentist']]

i've tried this: [x for x in test if re.sub(r'^\d{1} / \d{2}','', x[0])] but it does not work.
What can i do to get the response i need?

your strings seem to have the format [number] [space] [/] [space] [number] [space] [text]  so you can just use split to separate into tokens [number, /, number, text, text, text, ...] and then discard the first 3 tokens  myString.split()[3:]

Why do you remove the fraction from the first and third, but not the second? Is there a more specific criterion for when to remove the fraction?

Your regexp only matches when the denominator is exactly 2 digits. That's why it doesn't work for 2 / 3.

@Barmar I believe they are removing from the first element of each sub list, first sub list has 2 elements, second sub list has 1, which makes it look like first and third

Just use for x in test: x[0] = re.sub(r'^\d+\s*/\s*\d+','', x[0])

It appears that you want to perform the replacement only on the first element of each sublist:
import re

test = [['6 / 24 hello','4 / 5 askdskjf'],['2 / 3 dentist']]
output = [[re.sub(r'^\d+ / \d+', '', x[0]), *x[1:]] for x in test]
print(output)

# [[' hello', '4 / 5 askdskjf'], [' dentist']]


You need to use *x[1:] to splice it. Your code makes the rest of the list a nested list.
